# Creating multiple feature-columns using apply (or something else) on pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [69, 77, 88],
                   'col2': ['barfoo', 'foo', 'bar']})
print(df)

   col1    col2
0    69  barfoo
1    77     foo
2    88     bar
```

Also I have function that returns two values based on string:

```
def get_first_n_second(string):
    '''
    Function returns two values for two columns
    '''
    value1 = string[0]
    value2 = string[1]
    return value1, value2
```

And I want to create two new columns based on col2 (it doesn`t work):

```
df[['first', 'second']] = df['col2'].apply(get_first_n_second)
```

Desired output:

```
   col1    col2   first   second
0    69  barfoo       b        a
1    77     foo       f        o
2    88     bar       b        a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 changes - return `Series` from function:

```
def get_first_n_second(string):
    '''
    Function returns two values for two columns
    '''
    value1 = string[0]
    value2 = string[1]
    return pd.Series([value1, value2])


df[['first', 'second']] = df['col2'].apply(get_first_n_second)
print (df)
   col1    col2 first second
0    69  barfoo     b      a
1    77     foo     f      o
2    88     bar     b      a
```

Comment: Yes, i mentiond mistake about apply on full dataframe. It was accidentally.

Comment: @Warrior404 - No problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: use the built in `str` methods.  It may(?) be more efficient to use the built in functions than `.apply`:

```
df['first'] = df['col2'].str[0]
df['second'] = df['col2'].str[1]
```

Comment: In this case, i think, your solution is better and easier, but there are more complex function in my real project. So `str` method dont have such methods. But thank you anyway.